# Displaying toString() of an object in JavaFX

Tags: java, text, javafx, tostring

I can't seem to properly display a toString() from a referenced object using JavaFX, I wasn't able to find anything on the matter. The search properly returns an object of type PostalCode,
however text() will not reference its toString(). Can someone explain how to make the toString viewable?

```
PostalCode closestFilteredPostalCode = postalCodeIndex.search(latitude, longitude);
TextBuilder.create().text(closestFilteredPostalCode).font(fontTitle).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, and it doesn't seem related to JavaFX.

`toText()` (or `text()` in your case) and `toString()` API usually have different use cases.

- `toText()` is used when the information will end up to the user. It's a translatable text that is user-readable.
- `toString()` is more for debugging purposes. You use it to display concise info about your objects.